# GWT vertical align labels and textboxes in java code

Tags: java, gwt, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align a label and 2 text boxes. I tried to use a horizontal panel, a grid and a flex table, but none of them seems to perfectly align the text. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post a sketch of what it's supposed to look like and what the other attempts get wrong.

Comment: I tried the HorizontalPanel with different alignments:
- top : https://gyazo.com/b5d6e74d99985fc2fefbd9ac36b1ef4f
- middle : https://gyazo.com/71dbceca3c8dd3cce1967ab66e7a7831
- bootom : https://gyazo.com/2239aa05f37d1b2ad74fd9e0370757c4

Comment: ControlGroup : https://gyazo.com/82d244b3868aca68dffb8a2f09f04904

Comment: We cannot help you based on an image. Maybe there is a margin or padding on top of your label. Maybe there is another div. Maybe something else. Have you examined it in your browser dev tools?

Comment: Yes, the main widget is just added to a container with only margins and paddings, I guess this doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.TOP);` in HorizontalPanel, but according to the documentation this property affects only widgets that have been added after this property has been set.
2. If you only support modern browsers, a better solution is to use [Flexbox layout model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: I tried the HorizontalPanel with different alignments:
- top : https://gyazo.com/b5d6e74d99985fc2fefbd9ac36b1ef4f
- middle : https://gyazo.com/71dbceca3c8dd3cce1967ab66e7a7831
- bootom : https://gyazo.com/2239aa05f37d1b2ad74fd9e0370757c4

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try it with Vertical panel to add widgets like label and textBox.

this can be useful to you, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_verticalpanel_widget.htm

Comment: I have to display them on a single "line", so I have to use a HorizontalPanel, but my problem is that they are not perfectly aligned vertically

Comment: What do you mean by they are not perfectly aligned.? If possible please create a demo mockup to show what you want.

Comment: for example here https://gyazo.com/71dbceca3c8dd3cce1967ab66e7a7831
you can see that the texts from the textboxes are not perfectly centered with the text from the label, in the same way, if i select the texts from the textboxes, the label's text is not perfectly centered with them

Comment: You can apply a custom css to those labels with margin-top property.

Comment: yeah, but this means to calculate the margins for each of them, how can I get the alignment done automatically?

Comment: Not necessary for each of them you have to create different css, but you can use/apply  a single css class for all of your labels.